# Retrieving the text of a specified link tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have a few links that have a class of 'button', and I am trying to get their text values with the jQuery .text() function, but it is returning nothing at the moment,

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var tester = $('a.test').text();

 alert(tester);
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class='test'>TEST</a>
```

any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Nvm, seem to have gotten it working, my jQuery library wasn't referenced properly! Noob mistake! Thanx anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, just try....

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="test">Test</a>

  <p></p>
<script>
   var string = $("a.test").text();
   alert(string);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```